# Format Date VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i want to implement this recorded macro into a macro for my code, i succesfully transformed "E" row into general, and i want to change that date into Short Date format DD/MM/YYYY the macro i recorded is this one below:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro

    Range("L4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(MID(RC[-7],1,10))"
    Range("L4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L4:L4500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("L4:L4500").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```

I tried it by making the function into the L Column, if it is possible i would like to implement it in one column so all values change and then paste them into the E column

The whole E column is like this:

- 01-10-2019 52:59:76
- 02-10-2019 52:59:76
- 02-10-2019 52:59:76
- 05-10-2019 52:59:76

And i want them to change into

- 01/10/2019
- 02/10/2019
- 02/10/2019
- 05/10/2019

This the code i used to transform the whole E column data to the format of dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss to correct the error of some data not changing into the correct format

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("E").Cells
    Columns("E").NumberFormat = "0"
    Columns("E").NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

Comment: Did you see my sent processed files? I can see that all previous comments disappeared...

Comment: No, i was going to check it today, could you share the link again ? please @FaneDuru

Comment: One is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mls_V9ahVVwU8Rnw50TwJHbna1jOz-oY) and the other one [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13iOUvbfj3P9NhdTJ5Mf-VNxsgwj-fPpP). They have been created using the code of my answer. When you open the .txt file in Excel, do not choose General format for column 5! Choose **Text**. When Excel finds cells having incorrect data format (more than 59 seconds) the format will be Text. If the cell contains date time format, it transform the date in double format. So, it is mandatory to choose **Text** format when load the file! Please confirm you did that.

Comment: I am working now to a piece of code processing your text files directly. It will replace the cases of time more then 59 seconds  with 59. That text file would be correctly opened in standard Excel. I mean, letting General formatting which Excel choose.

Comment: Don't you have any feedback?

Comment: @FaneDuru there's only a word file, im checking them, yesterday i didn't have the time, i would like to see how did you do it, i solved it yesterday with an array and making two private functions so it could work.

Comment: @FaneDuru also i don't make the procedure of generating those .txt files, i notified them that their registration process is wrong because a day doesn't have 56 hours but got mad attitude for that and told me to fix their crap hahaha

Comment: i would appreciate it if you could share with me a dropbox/drive link with the code of the both solutions you came up with, i really want to learn and i appreciate the time you spent with my questions, im grateful @FaneDuru

Comment: But, I explained you more than clear... I used **the posted code** of my answer, on your text file, but opened like I explained. You did not confirm anything about your result! Seeing that I am more interested than you in solving of your problem, I must confess that I started to ask myself why do I loose my weekend time to solve a problem which does not help me at all, when you are not able, at least, to check my answer. Initially I was expected a confirmation that the code **like it is** works, to prove to people not understanding, but voting it down, are wrong. Now, i don't care anymore...

Comment: I told you it throwed me an error on the last line about the condition without end if, you told me you were gonna check it and then post it again, i waited for that @FaneDuru

Comment: I thought I did that... I corrected it. Please refresh the page and use the code like it is (now).

Comment: Already tried it, it's more neat than the one i did, thank you a lot for the time you invested in my question, i just had to put a sub to eliminate the hh:mm:ss but it is as i asked, thank you a lot m8! I upvoted the code and it really works, it totally ignores the bad format of the HH:MM:SS that are in the .txt file and changes it into the format one wishes @FaneDuru

Comment: Welcome! I would just like to post such a comment at my answer. Only for people who coldn't understand the code, but votting down...

Comment: Already putted something so someone else can see that it works and can use it if they encounter the same problem as i did @FaneDuru :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If in '01-10-2019 52:59:76' first two digits means day, try please the next code:

```
Sub testDateFormat()
  Dim lastRow As Long, sh As Worksheet, x As String, i As Long
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet, if not active one
     lastRow = sh.Range("E" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
     sh.Range("E1:E" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If sh.Range("E" & i).Value <> Empty Then
            If chkFind(CStr(sh.Range("E" & i).Value)) = True Then
               x = CStr(sh.Range("E" & i).Value)
               sh.Range("E" & i).Value = Format(DateSerial(Split(left(x, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", x) - 1), "-")(2), _
                           Split(left(x, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", x) - 1), "-")(1), _
                           Split(left(x, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", x) - 1), "-")(0)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
            Else
                Debug.Print "Unusual string on the row " & i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Private Function chkFind(strVal As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
     If WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", strVal) = 11 Then
        chkFind = True
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
           Err.Clear
           On Error GoTo 0
           chkFind = False
        End If
     Else
        chkFind = False
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

If first digits represents month, then the last two array (split) elements must be vice versa:

`Split(left(x, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", x) - 1), "-")(0), _
                           Split(left(x, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", x) - 1), "-")(0))`

instead of

`Split(left(x, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", x) - 1), "-")(1), _
                           Split(left(x, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", x) - 1), "-")(1))`

Comment: What is incorrect in my code to vote it down? Can you explain base on what did you that? I'm addressing to the one who voted down... It will work independent of the way would General  format transformed the value.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but I can you right now that it needs data validation. Before you do any string manipulation, you need to make sure that what you're working with is a valid DateTime formatted string. I think that's at the core of the OP's real problem...

Comment: @Frank Ball: My code doesn't care about the cell value. I mean if is DateTime or string. It doesn't care about the strange seconds which I observed. It transforms the cell value in string, extract the 10 left digits string, transform it in date using DateSerial after splitting on "-" character and format it according to that...

Comment: I think that the source data is unreliable.  What you have will work if the source data is reliable, but the fact that it has 76 seconds in it brings the integrity of the data into question.  In these cases data validation is must and while your code will work for valid data, it will fail if that source sends you 04/31/2020 (an invalid date).

Comment: @Frank Ball: It is obvious that the source data is unreliable! But this is the real challenge which my code solves. It processes only the first 11 digits of the string date, in order to offer what he requested. I tested the code on the files sent by him and it perfectly worked! He did not say that the 'source data' is, in fact, a text file which he opens in Excel. When the file is opened (| delimited), letting Excel to open the column with General format will obtain strings for unreliable cells and date in case of seconds less or equal with 59. So, opening it like text, the code works perfect.

Comment: @Frank Ball:  If I would know the origine of the file (txt file) I could provide a code able to only (directly) change the seconds group which exceeds 59 in 59. And such a text file will be correctly open (like date) by Excel...

Comment: It works perfectly, didn't have a single issue with the code and can work with the bad  format the .txt files like in my case.